# SYMFONY4 : "Notice: Undefined variable: parentClass"

Tags: php, symfony

I've got this error message when i try to go to a page which calls an entity. (For example the contact page, or articles page)

"Notice: Undefined variable: parentClass" which refer me to this file 
vendor\doctrine\persistence\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry.php line 176

```
public function getManagerForClass($class)
{
    // Check for namespace alias
    if (strpos($class, ':') !== false) {
        [$namespaceAlias, $simpleClassName] = explode(':', $class, 2);
        $class                              = $this->getAliasNamespace($namespaceAlias) . '\\' . $simpleClassName;
    }
    $proxyClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
    if ($proxyClass->implementsInterface($this->proxyInterfaceName)) {
        $parentClass = $proxyClass->getParentClass();
        if (! $parentClass) {
            return null;
        }
    }
        $class = $parentClass->getName();
    foreach ($this->managers as $id) {
        $manager = $this->getService($id);
        if (! $manager->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($class)) {
            return $manager;
        }
    }
}
```

I really dont know what to do. 
If someone got an idea or already had this error :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your correctly indented code looks like this:

```
$proxyClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
if ($proxyClass->implementsInterface($this->proxyInterfaceName)) {
    $parentClass = $proxyClass->getParentClass();
    if (! $parentClass) {
        return null;
    }
}
$class = $parentClass->getName();
```

now, in the case that `$proxyClass->implementsInterface(...)` is `FALSE` there is no `$parentClass` defined, hence the error message.

since the code appears to be in doctrine, maybe it's a bug. Maybe it was fixed and you use an old version for some reason. maybe update?

[in the current version the line is inside the if-block](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/779661acceefe09bd0e709b4cfe65ec0213f0d5c/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/AbstractManagerRegistry.php#L183)

Answer (score 0):

you're absolutely right, i don't know why `$class = $parentClass->getName();` was out the 'if', the problem was effectively this ! Thank you !